# How to send/load data from a Tab through a controller to another Tab in a MVVM pattern (JavaFx 8)

Tags: mvvm, tabs, javafx-8, fxml

I developed a project in JavaFx 8, where I am able to send or load data from one tab to another tab. Now I want to develop the same project in a MVV pattern. 
Now I made a view, viewmodel and model for each tab and the maincontroller, which should handle the other tabs.

[Tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AINCR.png)

I am able to set the text in tab1 and in tab2, but I don't know how build the maincontroller model/modelview to handle the data from tab1 to tab2. If I want to bind the mainconcontrollerview to the maincontrollermodel, I can't because of the fxml annotation.

In the maincontroller view are the other two views included. I provided the classes and the fxml documents to give a much better understanding what I have done so far and where my problems could lie

[MVVM TabTest link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7iTnlcy161ZZ2Ztemc5UWp2NjQ)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to re-invent the wheel you should maybe have a look at a framework which implements the MVVM pattern and also provides the necessary means for communication between components.

https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX

Answer (score 0):

1) There are some misconceptions in your code regarding MVVM. 
The "View" in MVVM consists of 2 things: The FXML file and a "CodeBehind" class. The codeBehind class is the class that has the references to the UI controls with the @FXML annotation. The codeBehind class then connects the UI controls to the properties of the ViewModel. So the classes in your "viewmodel" package are actually the codeBehind class that belong to the "View". And the classes in your "model" package are actually your "ViewModels".

2) In your example each tab codeBehind class has a reference to the main codeBehind class and the main codeBehind has references to each tab codeBehind which means you have an extremely tight coupling. For a parent component it is ok to know it's children but child components shouldn't know where and how they are used.

3) I'm one of the developers of the [mvvmFX](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX) framework. Like [mipa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37464417/804451) said this framework provides some helpers and utilities for situations like this. I think there are 2 ways of doing this:

1. You should use [dependency-injection](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/Dependency-Injection). This way in the main viewModel you can get references to both tab viewModels and connect them without the need for the codeBehind classes to know each other.
2. In the last version of the framework we introduced a beta feature which we called "scopes". It's basically a class that is indented to keep data that is used by several viewModels. ViewModels can inject the scope instance and use this data (for examply via databinding). This way ViewModels don't need direct knowledge of other ViewModels but only know the Scope instance. When at a later point in time a new tab is added, the existing classes don't need to be changed. You can find out more [here](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/wiki/Scopes).